# Display tooltip in draw item hover event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show tooltip on `ListBox`, so in load form I have:

```
        lstTech.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        var techListQuery = $"exec getTaskAssignableEmployeeList";

           var techList = db.GetTableBySQL(techListQuery);


            lstTech.DataSource = techList.ToList();
            lstTech.DisplayMember = "Abbreviation";
            lstTech.ValueMember = "EmpGuid";
```

Then in DrawItem method I have:

```
  private void lstTech_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox senderListBox = (ListBox)sender;
            if (e.Index < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var item = ((DataRowView)senderListBox.Items[e.Index]);
            var abbr = senderListBox.GetItemText(item["Abbreviation"]);
            var name = senderListBox.GetItemText(item["Name"]);

            e.DrawBackground();

            using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(abbr, e.Font, br, e.Bounds);
            }

            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected )
            {
                ttTechs.Show(name, senderListBox, e.Bounds.Right, senderListBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y);
            }

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
```

Then I want to disappear Tooltip on mouse leave like:

```
 private void lstTech_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox senderListBox = (ListBox)sender;
            ttTechs.Hide(senderListBox);
        }
```

So now Tooltip works, it appear when I clic on some item of list, problem is I don't want it on clic, I want it in `Hover` event. So I try:

```
  private void lstTech_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox senderListBox = (ListBox)sender;
            ttTechs.Show(senderListBox);
        }
```

But it returns me an error:

> No overload for method 'Show' takes 1 arguments

What am I doing wrong? what I need to display tooltip on hover event and remove from click event? Regards

**Update**

As answer below I change code to:

```
 //Set tooltip as Global variable
  ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();

  //Create new method to assign Draw
  private void SetToolTipText()
        {
            var content = string.Empty;
              foreach (DataRowView list in lstTech.SelectedItems)
               {
            var techName = list[1].ToString();
            content += techName + Environment.NewLine;
               }
            toolTip.SetToolTip(lstTech, content);
        }
          //Draw method
    private void lstTech_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            SetToolTipText();
        }
```

Problem is list items are invisible, if I click in listbox Tooltip appears correctly but list is not displayed. If I remove    `lstTech.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;` from `load_form` listbox items appears again but tooltip stop working. What is going on there?

Comment: What is `ttTechs`? Your ToolTip? If so have use used a regular `Form` to design a tool tip? There's no need for that, there's already a `ToolTip` control.

Comment: And you get the error because there's no `Show()` method that takes in an object of type `ListBox` as a parameter.

Comment: `ttTechs` is my tooltip, and yes I use `Design` to include that tooltip @Sach

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you want to use a form for a tool tip? That's a highly unusual practice. You can easily make use of the already available ToolTip which has all this functionality built in.

Comment: I want to use that because I want to show only abbreviation of names in a listBox and I want to show complete name in hover action. That's a requirement from my client, for me I can keep just showing complete name in listBox and done but clients today are too demanding, they dont care your recomendations @Sach

Comment: Yes but you can do that with a tool tip control. I'll show with an example.

Comment: Alright. I appreciate it @Sach

Answer (score 1):

There's a `ToolTip` control in `WinForms` which you can make use of.

Let's say your list box contains a bunch of names, and I want to only display the first 3 letters of each name on the tool tip. So I would write a function to go through each item in the list box and filter the names and create a string, then set it to the tool tip.

```
private void SetToolTipText()
{
    var content = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        var first3 = item.ToString().Substring(0, 3);
        content += first3 + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    toolTip.SetToolTip(listBox1, content);
}
```

Note that the `toolTip` is a global variable in my `Form`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Next I would call that function in my `DrawItem()` event like so:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    SetToolTipText();
}
```

In your program, instead of taking the first 3 characters of the string, do whatever the filtering you do.

Comment: Tooltip works, but for some reason my list text disappear, but if I clic in  blank space tooltip appears as desire, but my list still showing in blank, any idea why it occurs?

Comment: I know why.. it's because in my load form I have `lstTech.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;`, but if I remove that line, now I can see list but tooltip don't works

Comment: @Pepe  it's the `.OwnerDrawFixed` and `.OwnerDrawVariable` modes that trigger the `DrawItem` event (you should also subscribe `MeasureItem()`). If in this mode you don't see the ListBox Items text, something is wrong in you `DrawItem` proc. I'ld say it's that strange indexing.